# Extract parts of a php array to client side

Tags: php, html, arrays, request

So I'm trying to centralize products in one central php file and have my client side php just request info so I only have to edit the central php file to add and remove products

my server side

```
 $varProduct= (

//      [0]      [1]   [2] [3 4 5 6 7]             [8]  
array("Title" , 0001 , 100, 0,0,1,1,0, "/womens/tops/s/2.png", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", "/womens/tops/s/2.jpg", 50  )

 )
```

In my html client side I want to display the title, the price [2] and the url [8] 
basically

```
for(i=o, i< $varProduct.length(), i++){

//display $varProduct[i][0];
//display the Image for $varProduct[i][8];
//display  $varProduct[i][2];

}
```

how can I put values in my server side file to my client side in within html tags? I need to display them inline will I be able to format the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($varProduct); $i++) {
    //full path -- then post pram
    $return =  sendPostData("http://stackoverflow.com/", array('parm1' => $varProduct[$i][0], 'parm2' => $varProduct[$i][0]));
    print_r($return);
}
?>

<?php

//send data function
function sendPostData($url, Array $post) {
    $data = "";
    foreach ($post as $key => $row) {
        $row = urlencode($row); //fix the url encoding
        $key = urlencode($key); //fix the url encoding                
        if ($data == "") {
            $data .="$key=$row";
        } else {
            $data .="&$key=$row";
        }
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: I need to post or get from the server side it's not in one file

Comment: @RyanWilliams check now

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: can I do this without curl? maybe set a js variable to the arrary and request the array then use js to display?

Comment: is curl automatically installed in most web hosting services i haven't used curl since i was in college

Comment: this throws an error $varProduct.length is called before requested

Comment: how is that different? my $varProduct is still undefined  on my side at line 2. Doesn't the post request happen only once the loop is entered? . my post request is sendPostData("myserver.php", ...) I'm using apache would that affect this at all?